# C++ GLFW GLEW LINK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawArrays@12 referenced in function _main and LINK1120 1 unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm using glfw and glew just to test drawing a triangle on the screen but when i added the code to draw the triangle it gives me a LINK2019 unresolved external symbol and a LINK1120 1 unresolved external error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLFW has failed to initialize");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Window has failed to initialize");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); 
    glewExperimental = true;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW failed to initialize");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    GLuint vaoID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    static const GLfloat verts[] = {
        // x, y, z
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint vboID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        glBufferData(vboID, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

and heres the Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies that i put

```
glfw3.lib
glfw3dll.lib
glew32.lib
glew32s.lib
```

btw I'm using VS 2017 as the ide

Comment: you also need to link opengl32.lib

Comment: ty it works now but there's no triangle but i know why cuz i have not added the shaders